# cakephp 1.3 - how can i allow login with phone_number and username at same time?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

please i need in cakephp1.3 to enable user to login with his username or phone_number at same time
i would really appreciates help
i have make a search but most of component in github or other sources for newer versions of cakephp

that's my auth.php file

```
App::import(array('Router', 'Security'));

/**
 * Authentication control component class
 *
 * Binds access control with user authentication and session management.
 *
 * @package       cake
 * @subpackage    cake.cake.libs.controller.components
 */
class AuthComponent extends Object {
/**
 * Maintains current user login state.
 *
 * @var boolean
 * @access private
 */
    var $_loggedIn = false;
/**
 * Other components utilized by AuthComponent
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler');
/**
 * A reference to the object used for authentication
 *
 * @var object
 * @access public
 */
    var $authenticate = null;
/**
 * The name of the component to use for Authorization or set this to
 * 'controller' will validate against Controller::isAuthorized()
 * 'actions' will validate Controller::action against an AclComponent::check()
 * 'crud' will validate mapActions against an AclComponent::check()
 * array('model'=> 'name'); will validate mapActions against model $name::isAuthorized(user, controller, mapAction)
 * 'object' will validate Controller::action against object::isAuthorized(user, controller, action)
 *
 * @var mixed
 * @access public
 */
    var $authorize = false;
/**
 * The name of an optional view element to render when an Ajax request is made
 * with an invalid or expired session
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $ajaxLogin = null;
/**
 * The name of the model that represents users which will be authenticated.  Defaults to 'User'.
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $userModel = 'User';
/**
 * Additional query conditions to use when looking up and authenticating users,
 * i.e. array('User.is_active' => 1).
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $userScope = array();
/**
 * Allows you to specify non-default login name and password fields used in
 * $userModel, i.e. array('username' => 'login_name', 'password' => 'passwd').
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
/**
 * The session key name where the record of the current user is stored.  If
 * unspecified, it will be "Auth.{$userModel name}".
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $sessionKey = null;
/**
 * If using action-based access control, this defines how the paths to action
 * ACO nodes is computed.  If, for example, all controller nodes are nested
 * under an ACO node named 'Controllers', $actionPath should be set to
 * "Controllers/".
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $actionPath = null;
/**
 * A URL (defined as a string or array) to the controller action that handles
 * logins.
 *
 * @var mixed
 * @access public
 */
    var $loginAction = null;
/**
 * Normally, if a user is redirected to the $loginAction page, the location they
 * were redirected from will be stored in the session so that they can be
 * redirected back after a successful login.  If this session value is not
 * set, the user will be redirected to the page specified in $loginRedirect.
 *
 * @var mixed
 * @access public
 */
    var $loginRedirect = null;
/**
 * The the default action to redirect to after the user is logged out.  While AuthComponent does
 * not handle post-logout redirection, a redirect URL will be returned from AuthComponent::logout().
 * Defaults to AuthComponent::$loginAction.
 *
 * @var mixed
 * @access public
 * @see AuthComponent::$loginAction
 * @see AuthComponent::logout()
 */
    var $logoutRedirect = null;
/**
 * The name of model or model object, or any other object has an isAuthorized method.
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $object = null;
/**
 * Error to display when user login fails.  For security purposes, only one error is used for all
 * login failures, so as not to expose information on why the login failed.
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $loginError = null;
/**
 * Error to display when user attempts to access an object or action to which they do not have
 * acccess.
 *
 * @var string
 * @access public
 */
    var $authError = null;
/**
 * Determines whether AuthComponent will automatically redirect and exit if login is successful.
 *
 * @var boolean
 * @access public
 */
    var $autoRedirect = true;
/**
 * Controller actions for which user validation is not required.
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 * @see AuthComponent::allow()
 */
    var $allowedActions = array();
/**
 * Maps actions to CRUD operations.  Used for controller-based validation ($validate = 'controller').
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 * @see AuthComponent::mapActions()
 */
    var $actionMap = array(
        'index'     => 'read',
        'add'       => 'create',
        'edit'      => 'update',
        'view'      => 'read',
        'remove'    => 'delete'
    );
/**
 * Form data from Controller::$data
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $data = array();
/**
 * Parameter data from Controller::$params
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $params = array();
/**
 * Method list for bound controller
 *
 * @var array
 * @access protected
 */
    var $_methods = array();
/**
 * Initializes AuthComponent for use in the controller
 *
 * @param object $controller A reference to the instantiating controller object
 * @return void
 * @access public
 */
    function initialize(&$controller) {
        $this->params = $controller->params;
        $crud = array('create', 'read', 'update', 'delete');
        $this->actionMap = array_merge($this->actionMap, array_combine($crud, $crud));
        $this->_methods = $controller->methods;

        $admin = Configure::read('Routing.admin');
        if (!empty($admin)) {
            $this->actionMap = array_merge($this->actionMap, array(
                $admin . '_index'   => 'read',
                $admin . '_add'     => 'create',
                $admin . '_edit'    => 'update',
                $admin . '_view'    => 'read',
                $admin . '_remove'  => 'delete',
                $admin . '_create'  => 'create',
                $admin . '_read'    => 'read',
                $admin . '_update'  => 'update',
                $admin . '_delete'  => 'delete'
            ));
        }
        if (Configure::read() > 0) {
            App::import('Debugger');
            Debugger::checkSessionKey();
        }
    }
/**
 * Main execution method.  Handles redirecting of invalid users, and processing
 * of login form data.
 *
 * @param object $controller A reference to the instantiating controller object
 * @return boolean
 * @access public
 */
    function startup(&$controller) {
        $isErrorOrTests = (
            strtolower($controller->name) == 'cakeerror' ||
            (strtolower($controller->name) == 'tests' && Configure::read() > 0)
        );
        if ($isErrorOrTests) {
            return true;
        }

        $methods = array_flip($controller->methods);
        $action = strtolower($controller->params['action']);
        $isMissingAction = (
            $controller->scaffold === false &&
            !isset($methods[$action])
        );

        if ($isMissingAction) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!$this->__setDefaults()) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->data = $controller->data = $this->hashPasswords($controller->data);
        $url = '';

        if (isset($controller->params['url']['url'])) {
            $url = $controller->params['url']['url'];
        }
        $url = Router::normalize($url);
        $loginAction = Router::normalize($this->loginAction);

        $allowedActions = array_map('strtolower', $this->allowedActions);
        $isAllowed = (
            $this->allowedActions == array('*') ||
            in_array($action, $allowedActions)
        );

        if ($loginAction != $url && $isAllowed) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($loginAction == $url) {
            if (empty($controller->data) || !isset($controller->data[$this->userModel])) {
                if (!$this->Session->check('Auth.redirect') && env('HTTP_REFERER')) {
                    $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', $controller->referer(null, true));
                }
                return false;
            }

            $isValid = !empty($controller->data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['username']]) &&
                !empty($controller->data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']]);

            if ($isValid) {
                $username = $controller->data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['username']];
                $password = $controller->data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']];

                $data = array(
                    $this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['username'] => $username,
                    $this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['password'] => $password
                );

                if ($this->login($data)) {
                    if ($this->autoRedirect) {
                        $controller->redirect($this->redirect(), null, true);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash($this->loginError, 'default', array(), 'auth');
            $controller->data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']] = null;
            return false;
        } else {
            if (!$this->user()) {
                if (!$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash($this->authError, 'default', array(), 'auth');
                    if (!empty($controller->params['url']) && count($controller->params['url']) >= 2) {
                        $query = $controller->params['url'];
                        unset($query['url'], $query['ext']);
                        $url .= Router::queryString($query, array());
                    }
                    $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', $url);
                    $controller->redirect($loginAction);
                    return false;
                } elseif (!empty($this->ajaxLogin)) {
                    $controller->viewPath = 'elements';
                    echo $controller->render($this->ajaxLogin, $this->RequestHandler->ajaxLayout);
                    $this->_stop();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $controller->redirect(null, 403);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$this->authorize) {
            return true;
        }

        extract($this->__authType());
        switch ($type) {
            case 'controller':
                $this->object =& $controller;
            break;
            case 'crud':
            case 'actions':
                if (isset($controller->Acl)) {
                    $this->Acl =& $controller->Acl;
                } else {
                    $err = 'Could not find AclComponent. Please include Acl in ';
                    $err .= 'Controller::$components.';
                    trigger_error(__($err, true), E_USER_WARNING);
                }
            break;
            case 'model':
                if (!isset($object)) {
                    $hasModel = (
                        isset($controller->{$controller->modelClass}) &&
                        is_object($controller->{$controller->modelClass})
                    );
                    $isUses = (
                        !empty($controller->uses) && isset($controller->{$controller->uses[0]}) &&
                        is_object($controller->{$controller->uses[0]})
                    );

                    if ($hasModel) {
                        $object = $controller->modelClass;
                    } elseif ($isUses) {
                        $object = $controller->uses[0];
                    }
                }
                $type = array('model' => $object);
            break;
        }

        if ($this->isAuthorized($type)) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash($this->authError, 'default', array(), 'auth');
        $controller->redirect($controller->referer(), null, true);
        return false;
    }
/**
 * Attempts to introspect the correct values for object properties including
 * $userModel and $sessionKey.
 *
 * @param object $controller A reference to the instantiating controller object
 * @return boolean
 * @access private
 */
    function __setDefaults() {
        if (empty($this->userModel)) {
            trigger_error(__("Could not find \$userModel. Please set AuthComponent::\$userModel in beforeFilter().", true), E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        $defaults = array(
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => Inflector::underscore(Inflector::pluralize($this->userModel)),
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'sessionKey' => 'Auth.' . $this->userModel,
            'logoutRedirect' => $this->loginAction,
            'loginError' => __('Login failed. Invalid username or password.', true),
            'authError' => __('You are not authorized to access that location.', true)
        );
        foreach ($defaults as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($this->{$key})) {
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
/**
 * Determines whether the given user is authorized to perform an action.  The type of
 * authorization used is based on the value of AuthComponent::$authorize or the
 * passed $type param.
 *
 * Types:
 * 'controller' will validate against Controller::isAuthorized() if controller instance is
 *              passed in $object
 * 'actions' will validate Controller::action against an AclComponent::check()
 * 'crud' will validate mapActions against an AclComponent::check()
 *      array('model'=> 'name'); will validate mapActions against model
 *      $name::isAuthorized(user, controller, mapAction)
 * 'object' will validate Controller::action against
 *      object::isAuthorized(user, controller, action)
 *
 */
    function isAuthorized($type = null, $object = null, $user = null) {
        if (empty($user) && !$this->user()) {
            return false;
        } elseif (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->user();
        }

        extract($this->__authType($type));

        if (!$object) {
            $object = $this->object;
        }

        $valid = false;
        switch ($type) {
            case 'controller':
                $valid = $object->isAuthorized();
            break;
            case 'actions':
                $valid = $this->Acl->check($user, $this->action());
            break;
            case 'crud':
                $this->mapActions();
                if (!isset($this->actionMap[$this->params['action']])) {
                    $err = 'Auth::startup() - Attempted access of un-mapped action "%1$s" in';
                    $err .= ' controller "%2$s"';
                    trigger_error(
                        sprintf(__($err, true), $this->params['action'], $this->params['controller']),
                        E_USER_WARNING
                    );
                } else {
                    $valid = $this->Acl->check(
                        $user,
                        $this->action(':controller'),
                        $this->actionMap[$this->params['action']]
                    );
                }
            break;
            case 'model':
                $this->mapActions();
                $action = $this->params['action'];
                if (isset($this->actionMap[$action])) {
                    $action = $this->actionMap[$action];
                }
                if (is_string($object)) {
                    $object = $this->getModel($object);
                }
            case 'object':
                if (!isset($action)) {
                    $action = $this->action(':action');
                }
                if (empty($object)) {
                    trigger_error(sprintf(__('Could not find %s. Set AuthComponent::$object in beforeFilter() or pass a valid object', true), get_class($object)), E_USER_WARNING);
                    return;
                }
                if (method_exists($object, 'isAuthorized')) {
                    $valid = $object->isAuthorized($user, $this->action(':controller'), $action);
                } elseif ($object) {
                    trigger_error(sprintf(__('%s::isAuthorized() is not defined.', true), get_class($object)), E_USER_WARNING);
                }
            break;
            case null:
            case false:
                return true;
            break;
            default:
                trigger_error(__('Auth::isAuthorized() - $authorize is set to an incorrect value.  Allowed settings are: "actions", "crud", "model" or null.', true), E_USER_WARNING);
            break;
        }
        return $valid;
    }
/**
 * Get authorization type
 */
    function __authType($auth = null) {
        if ($auth == null) {
            $auth = $this->authorize;
        }
        $object = null;
        if (is_array($auth)) {
            $type = key($auth);
            $object = $auth[$type];
        } else {
            $type = $auth;
            return compact('type');
        }
        return compact('type', 'object');
    }
/**
 * Takes a list of actions in the current controller for which authentication is not required, or
 * no parameters to allow all actions.
 */
    function allow() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        if (empty($args) || $args == array('*')) {
            $this->allowedActions = $this->_methods;
        } else {
            if (isset($args[0]) && is_array($args[0])) {
                $args = $args[0];
            }
            $this->allowedActions = array_merge($this->allowedActions, $args);
        }
    }
/**
 * Removes items from the list of allowed actions.
 *
 * @see AuthComponent::allow()
 * @access public
 */
    function deny() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach ($args as $arg) {
            $i = array_search($arg, $this->allowedActions);
            if (is_int($i)) {
                unset($this->allowedActions[$i]);
            }
        }
        $this->allowedActions = array_values($this->allowedActions);
    }
/**
 * Maps action names to CRUD operations. Used for controller-based authentication.
 *
 */
    function mapActions($map = array()) {
        $crud = array('create', 'read', 'update', 'delete');
        foreach ($map as $action => $type) {
            if (in_array($action, $crud) && is_array($type)) {
                foreach ($type as $typedAction) {
                    $this->actionMap[$typedAction] = $action;
                }
            } else {
                $this->actionMap[$action] = $type;
            }
        }
    }
/**
 * Manually log-in a user with the given parameter data.  The $data provided can be any data
 */
    function login($data = null) {
        $this->__setDefaults();
        $this->_loggedIn = false;

        if (empty($data)) {
            $data = $this->data;
        }

        if ($user = $this->identify($data)) {
            $this->Session->write($this->sessionKey, $user);
            $this->_loggedIn = true;
        }
        return $this->_loggedIn;
    }
/**
 * Logs a user out, and returns the login action to redirect to.
 *
 */
    function logout() {
        $this->__setDefaults();
        $this->Session->del($this->sessionKey);
        $this->Session->del('Auth.redirect');
        $this->_loggedIn = false;
        return Router::normalize($this->logoutRedirect);
    }
    
    function fb_logout() {
        $this->__setDefaults();
        $this->Session->del($this->sessionKey);
        $this->Session->del('Auth.redirect');
        $this->_loggedIn = false;
    }
/**
 * Get the current user from the session.
 *
 */
    function user($key = null) {
        $this->__setDefaults();
        if (!$this->Session->check($this->sessionKey)) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($key == null) {
            return array($this->userModel => $this->Session->read($this->sessionKey));
        } else {
            $user = $this->Session->read($this->sessionKey);
            if (isset($user[$key])) {
                return $user[$key];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
/**
 * If no parameter is passed, gets the authentication redirect URL.


 */
    function redirect($url = null) {
        if (!is_null($url)) {
            $redir = $url;
            $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', $redir);
        } elseif ($this->Session->check('Auth.redirect')) {
            $redir = $this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');
            $this->Session->delete('Auth.redirect');

            if (Router::normalize($redir) == Router::normalize($this->loginAction)) {
                $redir = $this->loginRedirect;
            }
        } else {
            $redir = $this->loginRedirect;
        }
        return Router::normalize($redir);
    }
/**
 * Validates a user against an abstract object.
 *
 */
    function validate($object, $user = null, $action = null) {
        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->user();
        }
        if (empty($user)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->Acl->check($user, $object, $action);
    }
/**
 * Returns the path to the ACO node bound to a controller/action.
 *

 */
    function action($action = ':controller/:action') {
        return str_replace(
            array(':controller', ':action'),
            array(Inflector::camelize($this->params['controller']), $this->params['action']),
            $this->actionPath . $action
        );
    }
/**
 * Returns a reference to the model object specified, and attempts
 * to load it if it is not found.

 */
    function &getModel($name = null) {
        $model = null;
        if (!$name) {
            $name = $this->userModel;
        }

        if (PHP5) {
            $model = ClassRegistry::init($name);
        } else {
            $model =& ClassRegistry::init($name);
        }

        if (empty($model)) {
            trigger_error(__('Auth::getModel() - Model is not set or could not be found', true), E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }

        return $model;
    }
/**
 * Identifies a user based on specific criteria.

 */
    function identify($user = null, $conditions = null) {
        if ($conditions === false) {
            $conditions = null;
        } elseif (is_array($conditions)) {
            $conditions = array_merge((array)$this->userScope, $conditions);
        } else {
            $conditions = $this->userScope;
        }
        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->user();
            if (empty($user)) {
                return null;
            }
        } elseif (is_object($user) && is_a($user, 'Model')) {
            if (!$user->exists()) {
                return null;
            }
            $user = $user->read();
            $user = $user[$this->userModel];
        } elseif (is_array($user) && isset($user[$this->userModel])) {
            $user = $user[$this->userModel];
        }

        if (is_array($user) && (isset($user[$this->fields['username']]) || isset($user[$this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['username']]))) {

            if (isset($user[$this->fields['username']]) && !empty($user[$this->fields['username']])  && !empty($user[$this->fields['password']])) {
                if (trim($user[$this->fields['username']]) == '=' || trim($user[$this->fields['password']]) == '=') {
                    return false;
                }
                $find = array(
                    $this->userModel.'.'.$this->fields['username'] => $user[$this->fields['username']],
                    $this->userModel.'.'.$this->fields['password'] => $user[$this->fields['password']]
                );
            } elseif (isset($user[$this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['username']]) && !empty($user[$this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['username']])) {
                if (trim($user[$this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['username']]) == '=' || trim($user[$this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['password']]) == '=') {
                    return false;
                }
                $find = array(
                    $this->userModel.'.'.$this->fields['username'] => $user[$this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['username']],
                    $this->userModel.'.'.$this->fields['password'] => $user[$this->userModel . '.' . $this->fields['password']]
                );
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            $model =& $this->getModel();
            $data = $model->find(array_merge($find, $conditions), null, null, 0);
            if (empty($data) || empty($data[$this->userModel])) {
                return null;
            }
        } elseif (!empty($user) && is_string($user)) {
            $model =& $this->getModel();
            $data = $model->find(array_merge(array($model->escapeField() => $user), $conditions));

            if (empty($data) || empty($data[$this->userModel])) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data)) {
            if (!empty($data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']])) {
                unset($data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']]);
            }
            return $data[$this->userModel];
        }
        return null;
    }


    function hashPasswords($data) {
        if (is_object($this->authenticate) && method_exists($this->authenticate, 'hashPasswords')) {
            return $this->authenticate->hashPasswords($data);
        }

        if (is_array($data) && isset($data[$this->userModel])) {
            if (isset($data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['username']]) && isset($data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']])) {
                $data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']] = $this->password($data[$this->userModel][$this->fields['password']]);
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function password($password) {
        return Security::hash($password, null, true);
    }

    function shutdown(&$controller) {
        if ($this->_loggedIn) {
            $this->Session->del('Auth.redirect');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

..........................................................................

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: CakePHP 1.3 is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a newer release!

Comment: @Salines that's why iam asking here , not at cakephp support pages

Comment: You should have inserted your php code, ie login method. i haven't used CakePHP 1.x for over 10 years so i forgot exactly how to solve your problem. I think that you must first use the find method, where you will search for these two parameters, if there is a result, then you need to supplement the data array.